# reactjs - creating separate modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my simple reactjs application. It all works fine but I would like to know how to create separate modules ie;I want to separate the components in script.js and add it another file and include it.

How can I do it in reactjs?

Currently, the application is not deployed on any server.

script.js:

```
var CreatePanel = React.createClass({ 
    render: function(){ 
        return <div className="row">
            <div className = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <input type="text"></input>
                <select></select>
            </div>
        </div>; 
    } 
}); 

var FilterPanel = React.createClass({ 
    render: function(){ 
        return <div className="row">Filter Panel</div>; 
    } 
}); 

React.render(<div class="container">
    <CreatePanel/>   
    <FilterPanel/> 
</div>
    , document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="fb.me/react-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>React Components</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./myscript.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Like webpack or browserify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flat out copy `CreatePanel` and `FilterPanel` components to different files and include them before `myscript.js`. It should look something like this:

createpanel.js

```
var CreatePanel = React.createClass({ 
    render: function(){ 
        return <div className="row">
            <div className = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <input type="text"></input>
                <select></select>
            </div>
        </div>; 
    } 
});
```

filterpanel.js

```
var FilterPanel = React.createClass({ 
    render: function(){ 
        return <div className="row">Filter Panel</div>; 
    } 
});
```

myscript.js

```
React.render(<div class="container">
    <CreatePanel/>   
    <FilterPanel/> 
</div>
    , document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="fb.me/react-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>React Components</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./createpanel.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./filterpanel.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./myscript.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this works, please do not do this on a public-facing website!

Comment: Apart from including Babel on production, what else is wrong here?

Comment: Even modern web browsers have parallel HTTP request limits (6 for Chrome IIRC) - each React component is now eating up a valuable request.  With the introduction of HTTP 2 this is less of an issue, but users stuck without will be forced to wait for every single request to complete before the page can finally render.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but around 70% of currently used browsers support HTTP2 and it's starting to become an anti-pattern to bundle resources. (I still do though.)

Comment: That's true - I still bundle resources as well because some tools can eliminate dead code (code that is never called) from any libraries I `require()` into my modules.  Your answer is correct, I just wanted to make sure the OP knew this *may not* be the "best" way to continue development on whatever website s/he is working on.

Comment: @frontsideair: what is the problem using Babel? should I use ES6 instead?

Comment: Also, I tried your above code and I get error - "unreachable code after return statement"

Comment: Opened a new issue - "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232385/unreachable-code-after-return-stmt"

Answer (score 2):

A common approach would be to make use of ES6 modules & class syntax for your React components. You would again separate out your components to individual files & export them:

CreatePanel.jsx

```
import React from 'react';    

export default class CreatePanel extends React.Component { 
  render() { 
    return 
      (<div className="row">
        <div className = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
          <input type="text"></input>
            <select></select>
        </div>
      </div>); 
  } 
};
```

FilterPanel.jsx

```
import React from 'react';    

export default class FilterPanel extends React.Component { 
  render() { 
    return <div className="row">Filter Panel</div>; 
  } 
});
```

Then you can import those components to your script.js where you are running React.render()

script.js

```
import React from 'react';

import CreatePanel from 'your relative path to CreatePanel.jsx';
import FilterPanel from 'your relative path to FilterPanel.jsx';

React.render(<div class="container">
<CreatePanel/>   
<FilterPanel/> 
</div>
, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```